# How to use Apache Camel in Clustered Environment with Zookeeper and ActiveMQ

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-zookeeper

I have 3 Servers (1 Master, 2 Slaves). Each of it have installed Zookeeper (latest version) and ActiveMQ "Classic".
ActiveMQ "Classic" is configured as Replicated Level-DB based on Zookeepers nodes.

Now I want to use Apache Camel for message routing.

Where should the Camel Route be located? I wrote a [Spring Boot App](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-spring-boot-activemq) but I want to have a failover like for ActiveMQ.

So I read about to put the jar into the ActiveMQ lib directory and setup an XML config [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://activemq.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html)

Another way is to use the Camel Components

- [Zookeeper Master Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/zookeeper-master-component.html)
- [Zookeeper Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/zookeeper-component.html)

Has anyone ever come across this problem before and want to share the solution?

Comment: LevelDB in ActiveMQ is deprecated and not supported, I would not consider using it in a production environment.

Comment: @Tim Bish, thank you for you hint. I'll try to configure with KahaDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh oh, as mentioned in the comments, **take care with the Level DB stuff** since it is **deprecated**. Only use it if you have tested it thoroughly! In our tests, it was running quite nice. But when the level DB was, for whatever reason, corrupted, the data was lost. **We were never able to restore a Level DB**. Not very nice for production.

And **don't even think about NFS based solutions**. NFS is really not suited for this, we had a lot of issues in our tests. We often managed it for example to have multiple masters or no masters at all. So we gave it up.

In the end we are using a **plain single broker** because the complexity of solving issues in master/slave or replication setups can be quite high. And we had almost never any unplanned downtimes despite our "single point of failure".

However, a bunch of people told me that a **network of brokers** works quite well to have a redundant setup. At least one of them was talking about a really big environment.

Well, this is **not really an answer to your question**, isn't it?

You can put **Camel routes beside the broker XML configuration** and these routes then run inside the ActiveMQ process. [See here for an example](https://activemq.apache.org/sample-camel-routes).

If you want to build a SpringBoot app to run the Broker, you simply need to make the **Camel context available in Spring** and it should be picked up.

Comment: Thank you to Share your experience. Network of brokers  sounds interesting but I'll try with Broker XML configuration first.